# Android Share Intent Image Sharing not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, uri, share-intent

I am new to Android and is having problem sharing image through share intent. I have googled alot, tried various things but still could not find the solution.

My code is:

```
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
            this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share with"),12);
```

I have checked the uri, the file saved is a bitmap and its returning file. But the image which shows during sharing is not valid. Gmail says it could not attach the attachment, messages app could not load the image.

Text sharing is working fine.

Basically I am writing a plugin for Unity. Here is my code on Unity Side:

```
string destination = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,"sharingImage" + ".png");
            if (!File.Exists(destination)) {
                print("creating new file");
                File.Create(destination);
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(destination, bytes);

            print("destination= "+destination);

            AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
            AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse","file://" + destination);

            using (AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.kashiftasneem.sharelib.ShareController")) {

                AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
                AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

                pluginClass.CallStatic("Share",message,uriObject,jo,gameObject.name,destination);
            }
```

I am logging destination and uri, they are:

> destination=
>   /data/data/com.kashiftasneem.shareandroidplugin2/files/sharingImage.png
>
> uri =
>   file:///data/data/com.kashiftasneem.shareandroidplugin2/files/sharingImage.png

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(idForSaveView);
        try {
            File file = new File(this.getExternalCacheDir(), "appdiam.png");
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            //fOut.close();
            file.setReadable(true, false);
            final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            intent.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

It might help.

Comment: I think it might be problem with uri.

Comment: I have edited the question to include more info related to uri.